# Make bibliography appear in toc as a chapter, not section

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies

Latex shows bibliography by default as a section. I want it to appear as a chapter.

My code is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\usepackage{apacite}
% ....
\bibliographystyle{apacite} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Βιβλιογραφία}
\bibliography{PhDthesis}
```

And the result looks like this:

```
Βιβλιογραφία                              153
      References . . . . .  . . . . . . . 153
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `\usepackage[nosectionbib]{apacite}`.

Answer (score 4):

From page 9 of the current (v6.03) [`apacite`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/apacite) documentation:

> `nosectionbib`
>   With this option, the bibliography is a chapter, if the
>   \chapter command is defined. Otherwise, it is always a section.

So you can use `\usepackage[nosectionbib]{apacite}`. You can additionally use the `numberedbib` option if you want the bibliography to appear as a numbered chapter or appendix (this option is *not* used in the below example).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{CMU Serif} % or any font supporting greek texts
\usepackage{xgreek}
\usepackage[nosectionbib]{apacite}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\bibname}{Βιβλιογραφία}} % change bib name
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{Sample Chapter}
  \bibliographystyle{apacite} 
  \bibliography{xampl} % sample bib file
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For Greek with `xgreek` you also need `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\bibname}{Βιβλιογραφία}}` in the preamble after having loaded `apacite`.