# 'fncychap' accidentally converts ToC bibliography entry from chapter to section

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, formatting, fncychap

I formatted my heading using the `fncychap` package. However, once applied it changes the format of my bibliography ToC entry from chapter to section (check the outline of the left image).

Compiling the file without the package shows the bibliography formatted as a chapter.

(My original preamble contains a lot more packages but I assume that these ones are the important ones.)

Is there a simple solution to this?

[image]

Minimal Code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{apacite}

\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}

\usepackage{hyperref}       

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\chapter{chapter 1}

This is a test reference \cite{R_mgcv}

\phantomsection
\bibliographystyle{apacite} 
\renewcommand\bibname{Bibliography}

\bibliography{Biblio}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\usepackage[nosectionbib]{apacite}` to load apacite. BTW, your example gives me `hyperref` errors at the `\cite` command.

Comment: Do you really need `\let\clearpage\relax`? if no  try to add `\makeatletter \let\st@rtbibsection\st@rtbibchapter \makeatother`

Comment: @touhami I just used `\let\clearpage\relax` to get a concise example on one page

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Make bibliography appear in toc as a chapter, not section](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/188140/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a consequence of the `apacite` package. It's default is to set the bibliography as a section (at least with the defaults of the `scrreprt` class). You can use the `nosectionbib` load option of the `apacite` package to make it a chapter:

```
\usepackage[nosectionbib]{apacite}
```

BTW, your example gives me `hyperref` errors at the `\cite` command. I suspect this is also an effect of `apacite`.

Comment: The error you get is because the 'cite' and 'bibliography' are personal. Did not find "a dummy example" for both while posting the question but wanted to provide a MWE. Suggestions are appreciated.